# PyQt spamming "select: Invalid argument" randomly when threading application

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qthread

I'm using PyQT (Qt version: 4.8.3, PyQt version 4.9.4) to create screenshots of a huge number of pages. I used a threaded strategy to improve performances.

It works like a charm for few seconds (about 30s) then suddenly the app just spams my terminal with a weird "**select: Invalid argument**" message.

It's not one of my debug message, for sure. But like this is really random, I can't really dig where/why this is happening.

If this can help, the more threads I spawn the faster it happens. Can this be a memory issue ?

I'm not sure if this can be useful, but here is the spawning method I'm using:

```
def spawn(self):
    worker = Worker() # this is a QObject
    thread  = QThread()
    # When done, respawn a new thread
    self.connect(worker, SIGNAL("done()"), self.spawn) 
    # And stop the related thread
    self.connect(worker, SIGNAL("done()"), thread.quit)
    self.threadsPool.append(thread) # Keep-alive
    self.workersPool.append(worker) # Keep-alive
    worker.moveToThread(thread)
    thread.start()
    worker.start("myfancydomain.com")
```

Thank you for you help!

Comment: "the more threads I spawn the faster it happens" this sounds like a race condition, or the threads using some shared resource like a network connection in a non-thread-safe way. I doubt the cause of the problem is in the code you posted, but I've honestly no idea how to properly diagnose this. Maybe trying to get stack traces with the  error message would help.

Answer (score 0):

It most likely has to do with access to a thread when it has been deleted.

I think your threadsPool is trying to access your thread after it has quit or deleted itself.  And somewhere there is a slot or function call by the threadsPool (or some similar container) that is accessing a bad pointer, such as a deleted thread.

To verify that this is the problem, in another thread or loop, go and query the number of threads in the threadsPool and some bit of information about each of the threads.  I bet after the first thread has quit, that it will crash when using the pointer to that thread.